# Streams: what has happened after instantiation but before reading?

Tags: c#, concepts, stream-processing

I'm trying to grok streams - my world is C# but I suspect the principles are general.

I understand the general principle of reading/writing bytes from/to a store. However, what I don't understand, specifically in a read scenario, is what has happened when you've created an instance of a stream (FileStream, for instance) but have not yet invoked any read methods.

e.g.

```
var fileStream = new FileStream( "Test.txt", FileMode.Open )
```

At this point the `fileStream.Length` property is available to me. This leads me to wonder the following:

- Has the FileStream class already read all the bytes in the file
  and ascertained the length of the file?
- Has the file been able to report its length to the FileStream?
- Is the file now already loaded into memory and the filestream is offering *that* up to me in a chunked fashion?
- Am I reading into memory the file's bytes at the time I call the read methods?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439798/471129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Has the FileStream class already read all the bytes in the file and ascertained the length of the file?
> - Has the file been able to report its length to the FileStream?

You can actually look for yourself at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1172). It looks as if it uses the `Win32Native`-API. Hence, getting the length of the stream is basically the same as right clicking a file, and viewing the "properties" of it. The size of the file is saved as meta-data. So in short; no, it does not read the entire file. From top to end, most implementations of `Stream` does not, this would defeat the purpose of streaming.

> - Is the file now already loaded into memory and the filestream is that up to me in a chunked fashion?

No, a `FileStream` is what it says on the tin, a file stream, it "streams" data from the file. If you copy the `FileStream` to a `MemoryStream`, then it's an in-memory stream.

> - Am I reading into memory the file's bytes at the time I call the read methods?

Yes.
To clarify, when you call `ReadByte()` you are reading one byte into memory, from the streams `Position`. When you call `Read()` you are reading the specified amount of bytes into memory (your `buffer`).

---

One of the main points of having a stream, is not to have to store something in memory. A byte-array does this, `MemoryStream` [is in fact basically a wrapper for a byte array/buffer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to all these questions is: **"You don't know!"**.

Please bear in mind that this is a *good* thing. The entire point of a stream class is to abstract from the tedious detail of how much to read when, and where to allocate the buffer to store stuff that you've already been given by the controller but not yet delivered to your caller. If you wanted to manage all that yourself, you might as well not use a stream and opt to work directly with `open()` and `read()` calls. Usually this is not what you want, so a typical stream class not only manages the details, but in fact hides them completely.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I think I comprehend that streams are an abstraction and to some extent I shouldn't be concerned about their implementation details. However, if some of my assumptions had been true, there would have been performance implications to using streams and certain of their methods/properties.

Comment: The question is specifically about `FileStream` and not any general implementation of `Stream`, you do in fact *know* whether it loads the file into memory or not.

Comment: @diemaus No, it isn't. It explicitly says "for instance" multiple times, and even with one particular class you only *know* what it promises in its API. Everything else might be implementation-defined or subject to change without notice. That is the only useful sense of "knowing what a component does" for a developer.

Comment: I have to admit that i just got "burned", I should've read the question more in detail, as you have done, excuses @KilianFoth. Either way: As I pointed out in my answer -- One of the purposes of streaming is to not have to load 'big lumps of data' into memory, one might assume when one finds a implementation of `Stream` that the entire stream source will not be loaded into memory. Wouldn't you agree with me on this?

Answer (score 1):

A FileStream has its length stored as data about the file. The file is not read yet. Think of a several-GB file - Reading it takes long. But returning the length is quick.

Some other types of Streams do *not* support seeking and therefore don't return Length. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx .

Only when you Read from the file are the bytes actually read from the media into memory. (Sometimes the OS might read ahead data that you did not yet read. But that is an OS implementation.)